# Custom Iterators

Tags: c++, iterator, gcc8

I tried to implement iterators for a class of mine and surprisingly I got the following:

> warning: ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second
>
> candidate 1: 'Iterator Iterator::operator+(const ptrdiff_t&) [with T = int; ptrdiff_t = long long int]'
>
> candidate 2: 'operator+(int, unsigned int)'

Here's the `Iterator` code:

```
template<typename T>
class Iterator {

public:

    Iterator(T *p = nullptr) { this->ptr = p; }
    Iterator(const Iterator<T>& iter) = default;

    Iterator<T>& operator=(const Iterator<T>& iter) = default;
    Iterator<T>& operator=(T* p) { this->ptr = p; return *this; }

    operator bool() const { return this->ptr ? true : false; }

    bool operator==(const Iterator<T>& p) const { return this->ptr == p.getConstPtr(); }
    bool operator!=(const Iterator<T>& p) const { return this->ptr != p.getConstPtr(); }

    Iterator<T>& operator+=(const ptrdiff_t& v) { this->ptr += v; return *this; }
    Iterator<T>& operator-=(const ptrdiff_t& v) { this->ptr -= v; return *this; }
    Iterator<T>& operator++() { ++this->ptr; return *this; }
    Iterator<T>& operator--() { --this->ptr; return *this; }
    Iterator<T> operator++(int) { auto temp(*this); ++this->ptr; return temp; }
    Iterator<T> operator--(int) { auto temp(*this); --this->ptr; return temp; }
    Iterator<T> operator+(const ptrdiff_t& v) { auto oldPtr = this->ptr; this->ptr += v; auto temp(*this); this->ptr = oldPtr; return temp; }
    Iterator<T> operator-(const ptrdiff_t& v) { auto oldPtr = this->ptr; this->ptr -= v; auto temp(*this); this->ptr = oldPtr; return temp; }

    ptrdiff_t operator-(const Iterator<T>& p) { return std::distance(p.getPtr(), this->getPtr()); }

    T& operator*() { return *(this->ptr); }
    const T& operator*() const { return *(this->ptr); }
    T* operator->() { return this->ptr; }

    T* getPtr() const { return this->ptr; }
    const T* getConstPtr() const { return this->ptr; }

private:

    T *ptr;

};
```

And here's how I `typedef` it inside my class:

```
template<typename T>
class ExampleClass {
    
public:

   // ...

   typedef Iterator<T>       iterator;
   typedef Iterator<const T> const_iterator;

   // ...

   iterator begin() { return iterator(&this->ptr()[0]); }
   iterator end() { return iterator(&this->ptr()[this->size()]); }
   const_iterator cbegin() { return const_iterator(&this->ptr()[0]); }
   const_iterator cend() { return const_iterator(&this->ptr()[this->size()]); }

   // ...

   // A function where I use the operator+
   void slice(unsigned int first, unsigned int last) {
        // ...
        auto it = this->begin() + first; // <--------
        // ...
   }

};
```

Maybe I am missing something but how `(Iterator, ptrdiff_t)` and `(int, unsigned int)` are ambiguous?

Comment: Cannot reproduce with given code, even with -Weverything. (clang++ -std=c++11 -Weverything)

Comment: @GillBates I will edit to add the function that uses the operator and triggers this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't compiled this, but the problem appears to be that `operator bool()`; it provides an implicit conversion to `bool`, which is, in turn, convertible to `int`. Iterators in general don't provide their own validation, so this is unusual. If you need it, mark it `explicit`. That will prevent the implicit conversion.

Comment: Yes, that was it. The thing is I used a lot of code I found online for the iterator class. Anyways, now I have another issue :P I can't use `std::distance` for my iterators because: `error: no type named 'difference_type' in 'struct std::iterator_traits<Iterator<int> >'`. Should I typedef `difference_type` inside my iterator class (and typedef to what?).

Comment: I add these: `using value_type = T;
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using pointer = T*;
        using reference = T&;
        using iterator_category = std::bidirectional_iterator_tag;` and it works.